# Visual Studio 2013 Template Deployment Failed Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create an web application with Azure. I'm receiving this error:

[Image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yccu6.png)

Text of the error:

> Template deployment failed. Deployment opertation statuses:
>   Failed:/subscription/d82232b1-4f78-43-e6c638fbc0/resourceGroups
>   s/Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS/provider/Microsft.Sql/server
>   s/contactmanager()error(InvalidApiVersionParameter): The api-version
>   '2.0' is invalid.The api version must be of the following format:
>   yyyy-MM-dd. This format supports the following suffices:'-preview,
>   -alpha,-beta,-rc,privatepreview'.

Comment: Please paste the error as text

Comment: I just edited, please help me

Comment: You will need to provide more details regarding what you're doing to invoke this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should look into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776326.aspx). Maybe it helps you to clarify the above, especially the "API Management REST API version history" tab

Comment: Thank you for the respond, im gonna look for this

Comment: Unfortunately the azure portal has new interface and i dont know how to to do the instruction that you provided.

Comment: that's bad, since I can't go to azure right now (I don't have subscribed anything now on azure), but this is maybe also something that you'd like to check out, in my opinion, it is the same issue as you had http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103327/asp-net-5-azure-template-deployment-failed-creating-sql-server

Comment: Thank you for the help, very much appreciated, I already see that and it solved my problem, but I wish in the future there is an easy way in this kind of situation. BTW Im new here how may I give you a plus reputation? so I can give you.

Comment: they might fix it in the meantime, maybe, or maybe not, it's something not upon us, unfortunately. But hey, I didn't had much of a hassle with Azure stuff (except the horrible docs back at that time), so I think this kind of occassional hiccups are still in the allowed tolerance. Last but not least, about a plus rep, feel free to give plus rep, if you consider that I really helped you, but it's not mandatory, but you know, it feels good if you do. Also I'm happy that you managed to fix your issue :)